# Python sharing DB connection with Multiple threads

Tags: python, multithreading, threadpool, mysql-python, python-multithreading

I am creating one database connection and I am sharing it across multiple threads (Around 100 to 1000 threads), I am getting the error as below,

> 1) What is wrong with my code ?

*This is My Sample code, I will change this code for below scenario:*
Based on some SQL result, It will create maximum of 1000 threads. 
**If I create database connection for each thread, It will create more database connections. In order to avoid this, I used the same database connection across all the threads, I am having only insert and update operations.**

> 2) Is there any better approach on this kind of multithreading
>   scenario ?

Error:

```
Worker: 0
Create Notification called for userid abcxyz and message is Test Message : Worker: 0 Attempt: 0
Sleeping ... 

Worker: 1
Create Notification called for userid abcxyz and message is Test Message : Worker: 1 Attempt: 0

Partial insertedID 43
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "T:\work\Testing\src\notification_data_feeder.py", line 58, in createNotification
    db.commit()
OperationalError: (2006, 'MySQL server has gone away')

Error on createNotification 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "T:\work\Testing\src\notification_data_feeder.py", line 54, in createNotification
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO push_notification_data (user_id, trig_time, msg, msg_prio, type, trig_ref, lang) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)", (str(userid), current_gmt_datetime, msg, msgPriority, '2', trigRef, lang))
  File "N:\Installation\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 174, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "N:\Installation\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
OperationalError: (2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query')

Error on createNotification
```

Code :

```
import json
import os
from random import randint
import threading
from time import sleep
import time, datetime
from urllib2 import Request, urlopen, HTTPError
import traceback
import MySQLdb
import socket
from collections import defaultdict

import CONST_LOCAL
from Notification import Notification
from Notification import UserDevice

def convertQueryResultToDevices(userDevicesRows, cursor): 
    userDevices = []
    if userDevicesRows is not None:
        for userDevicesRow in userDevicesRows:
            userDevice = UserDevice()
            userDevice.userId = userDevicesRow[0]
            userDevice.deviceId = userDevicesRow[1]
            userDevice.deviceType = userDevicesRow[2]
            userDevices.append(userDevice);
    return userDevices;  

def getDeviceIdsByUser(userId, cursor):
    userDevices = None;
    try :
        cursor.execute("SELECT uuid, registration_id, device_type  FROM userid_data WHERE userid = %s", (userId));
        userDevicesRows = cursor.fetchall()
        # Convert SQL Row to model object
        userDevices = convertQueryResultToDevices(userDevicesRows, cursor)   
    except:
        print(traceback.format_exc())

    return userDevices;

def createNotification(userid, msg, msgPriority, type, trigRef, lang, db, cursor):
    print("Create Notification called for userid " + str(userid) + " and message is " + msg)    
    try:
        # Insert the notification message
        current_gmt_datetime = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.mktime(time.gmtime()));
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO notification_data (user_id, triger_time, msg, msg_prio, type, trig_ref, lang) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)", (str(userid), current_gmt_datetime, msg, msgPriority, '2', trigRef, lang))

        insertedID = cursor.lastrowid
        print("Partial insertedID " + str(insertedID))

        # Commit this insertion
        if db:
            db.commit()

        # Get Devices of the user
        userDevices = getDeviceIdsByUser(userid, cursor)
        if userDevices is not None:
            for userDevice in userDevices:
                deviceId = userDevice.deviceId
                deviceType = userDevice.deviceType
                # If the value exists
                if deviceId:
                    # Default value
                    deviceTypeInt = 1;

                    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO notification_status (notification_id, device_id, device_type, status, attempts, delivery_status, delivery_err_reason) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)", (insertedID, deviceId, deviceTypeInt, 0, 0, 0, 0))

            # Commit this status row of the previous inserted data row
            if db:
                db.commit()

        print("Notification created , notification id " + str(insertedID))  
    except MySQLdb.Error, e:
        print(traceback.format_exc())
        print("Error on createNotification ")

def worker(num, attempt, db, cursor):
    """thread worker function"""
    for i in range(attempt):
        print 'Worker: %s' % num
        message = "Test Message : Worker: " + str(num) + " Attempt: " + str(i)
        createNotification("abcxyz", message, 1, 1, 1, 1, db, cursor)
        # Sleep for testing purpose
        sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    threads = []
    attempt = 1

    try:
        # Create DB connection, It will be shared across all threads
        db = MySQLdb.connect(CONST_LOCAL.DATABASE_SERVER, CONST_LOCAL.DATABASE_USER, CONST_LOCAL.DATABASE_PASSWORD, CONST_LOCAL.DATABASE_NAME)
        cursor = db.cursor()

        # Create Two threads, Each thread will insert one entry
        for i in range(2):
            t = threading.Thread(target=worker, args=(i, attempt, db, cursor))
            threads.append(t)
            t.start()
    except:
        print(traceback.format_exc())

    print("Sleeping ... ")
    # Testing purpose
    sleep(50000)
    print("Completed ... ")
```